# Surface Integral without using Gauss Divergence Theorem

Tags: vector-analysis, surface-integrals, multiple-integral, divergence-theorem

Evaluate $\iint_s $$\vec{F}\cdot $$\vec{dS}$ where $\vec{F}=4xi-2y^2j+z^2k$ and $S$ is the surface bounding the region $x^2+y^2=4, z=0$  and $z=3$

> When I solve it by Gauss Divergence Theorem it's answer was 84$\pi$ but again when I tried to verified it by direct integral it doesn't gives me the same answer.

```
Please Don't use Cylindrical Coordinate system :)
```

Comment: Could you please add your attempts?

Comment: well I think Problem in finding the answer comes when i have to find the Surface integral through the curved surface of cylinder Can you suggest how to approach?

Comment: Most likely the reason divergence theorem doesn't work for you is because you didn't take into account all three surface integrals you need and only did one surface integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the divergence theorm.

$\iiint 4+2y+2z\ dV$

Integrating with respect to $z$

$\iint (\int_0^3 4+2y+2z \ dz) \ dA$

$\iint 12 + 3y+ 9 \ dA$

The region is symmetric around the y axis, that term will drop on integration.

$21(4\pi) = 84\pi$  we agree on that!

Evaluating the surfaces independently.  We have two disks and the wall of the cyinder.

$z = 0$  The normal is $(0,0,-1).$  Negative, because we want the normals pointing out.

$F\cdot n = -2z$  But z is zero.

$0$ on that disk.

$z = 3, n = (0,0,1)$

$\iint  6 \ dA  = 24\pi$

You don't want to convert to cylindrical, we can paramertize by $x,z$

$y = \pm\sqrt{4-x^2}$

We can take the positive root and double the integral to cover both the positive and negative cases.

$n = (-\frac {\partial y}{\partial x}, 1, -\frac {\partial y}{\partial z}) = (\frac{x}{\sqrt {4-x^2}}, 1 , 0)$

$F\cdot n = \frac {4x^2}{\sqrt {4-x^2}} + 2\sqrt {4-x^2}$

$2\int_0^3 \int_{-2}^2 \frac {4x^2}{\sqrt{4-x^2}} + 2\sqrt {4-x^2} \ dx \ dz\\
2\int_0^3 \int_{-2}^2 \frac {4x^2 + 8 - 2x^2}{\sqrt {4-x^2}}\ dx \ dz\\
2\int_0^3 \int_{-2}^2 \frac {2x^2}{\sqrt{4-x^2}} + \frac{8}{\sqrt {4-x^2}}\ dx \ dz$

$x = 2\sin\theta, dx = 2\cos \theta.$  While this is a Calc 1 substitution, it is effectively the same thing as converting to cylindrical...

$2\int_0^3 \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac \pi2} 4\sin^2\theta + 8 \ dx \ dz\\
2\int_0^3 10\pi \ dz\\
60\pi$

$60\pi + 24\pi = 84\pi$

Comment: But i read when we convert $ds$ into $dxdz$ we have to divide it by $\mod{n.j}$

Comment: Technically, yes, but it is a factor that cancels out -- $\iint F(x,y,z)  d\vec S = \iint F(x,y,z)\cdot \frac {\vec n}{\|n\|} dS = \iint F(x,y,z)\cdot \frac {\vec n}{\|n\|} \|r_x\times r_y\| \ dx\ dy.$  But, $\vec n = (r_x\times r_y)$ and the $\|r_x\times r_y\|$ factors cancel.

Comment: Had I chosen a normal $n$ such as $(x,y,0)$ which is also normal to the surface, but not equal to $(r_x \times r_y).$ I would have to unitize the normal vector.

Comment: Look I read $\iint_s $$\vec{F}\cdot $$\vec{dS}$ =$\iint_r $$\vec{F}\cdot $$\vec{n} $(dxdz/|n.j|)